# Simultaneous diagonalizability of three endomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra

So I understand two endomorphisms on a finite dimensional vector space are simultaneously diagonalisable if (and only if) they commute.

But suppose we have three endomorphisms a, b and c.
What is the 'iff' condition for simultaneous diagonalisability here. Is it pair wise commute or is it, say, a commutes with both b and c.

The question arises from quantum mechanics.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, one should specify that the endomorphisms are diagonalisable; there exists commuting matrices (and thus endomorphisms) which are not all diagonalisable. (Just take for example the identity and a non-diagonalisable endomorphism)

In general, one has that for $A_1, \ldots , A_r$ diagonalisable endomorphisms on a finite dimensional vector space, that they are simultaneously diagonalisable if and only if they [commute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices). (i.e. pairwise commute) A proof can be found [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/minpolyandappns.pdf), Theorem 5.1.

Comment: With $A_1,\ldots,A_r$ diagonalizable endomorphisms on a finite dimensional vector space, am I correct that this is equivalent to $\prod_{i=1}^r A_{\sigma(i)} = \prod_{i=1}^r A_{i}$, $\forall \sigma \in S_r$?

Comment: Haha thanks Ivan.

Comment: @NicholasStull not exactly. If $A_i$ pairwise commute, then we can derive the condition you stated. However, it is possible for your condition to hold, and that $A_i$ do not pairwise commute (i.e. not  simultaneously diagonalisable) As an example, take $A_1$ to be the trivial zero map (which is diagonalisable), then your equation holds trivially for all $A_2, \ldots , A_r$ regardless of whether they pairwise commute.